# How do I make a simple character controller in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in sprite kit and in order to move my character I am applying an impulse but that is a problem because that moves him every 50 pixels or so. My question is, could someone please show me how to make a simple character controller so my character can move continuously until the user lets go from holding down the screen?

My GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let character = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "character"))
var move = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    //world
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)


    //character
    character.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
    character.setScale(0.2)
    character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
    character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(character)
    character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true




    //platform 1
    var platform = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform"))
    platform.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
    platform.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform.setScale(0.25)
    platform.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform)

    //platform 2
    var platformTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.4, self.frame.size.height * 0.3)
    platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform2.size)
    platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform2.setScale(0.25)
    platform2.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform2.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform2.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform2)


    //platform main
    var platformTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + platform3.size.height / 3)
    platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform3.size)
    platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform3.setScale(1)
    platform3.size.width = platform3.size.width * CGFloat(2.0)
    platform3.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform3.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform3.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform3)

    }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -50, dy: 0))
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 0))
                        }
    }



    func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        character.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
}




 func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to maintain a variable to keep track of the state of the touch events (left, right, or none). Here are the basic steps:

1. In `touchesBegan`, set touch state variable to left or right
2. In `update`, apply impulse continuously while user is touching the screen
3. In `touchesEnded`, reset the touch state variable

Here's an example of how to implement this...

Above `GameScene` class definition, add the following

```
enum TouchState {
    case Left
    case Right
    case None
}
```

In `GameScene`, add the following variable

```
var touchLocation:TouchState = .None
```

In `GameScene`, add or replace the following methods

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    // Apply impulse to physics body while users is touching the screen
    switch (touchState) {
    case .Left:
        character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -1, dy: 0))
    case .Right:
        character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 0))
    case .None:
        break
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            touchState = .Left
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            touchState = .Right
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Update touch status
    touchState = .None
}
```

Here's the GameScene.swift...

```
import SpriteKit

enum TouchLocation {
    case Left
    case Right
    case None
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "character")

    var touchLocation:TouchLocation = .None

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        //character
        character.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width * 0.5, view.frame.size.height * 0.5)
        character.setScale(0.1)
        character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
        character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.addChild(character)
        character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


        //platform 1
        var platform = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform"))
        platform.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width * 0.6, CGRectGetMidY(view.frame))
        platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
        platform.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        platform.setScale(0.25)
        platform.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        platform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        platform.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        self.addChild(platform)

        //platform 2
        var platformTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
        var platform2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
        platform2.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width * 0.4, view.frame.size.height * 0.3)
        platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform2.size)
        platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        platform2.setScale(0.25)
        platform2.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        platform2.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        platform2.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        self.addChild(platform2)


        //platform main
        var platformTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
        var platform3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
        platform3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(view.frame) + platform3.size.height / 3)
        platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform3.size)
        platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        platform3.setScale(1)
        platform3.size.width = platform3.size.width * CGFloat(2.0)
        platform3.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        platform3.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        platform3.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        self.addChild(platform3)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        switch (touchLocation) {
        case .Left:
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -1, dy: 0))
        case .Right:
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 0))
        case .None:
            break
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch:AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
                touchLocation = .Left
            } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
                touchLocation = .Right
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        touchLocation = .None
    }
}
```

Comment: When I write the switch statement in the update function I get an error saying, "Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type '<<error type>>'"

Comment: Are you sure you copied/pasted the exact code into your GameScene?

Comment: Yes, do you think you could paste the entire file if you have it so I don't mess anything up?

Comment: I've added the entire GameScene file

Comment: It does not move at all when I paste. That's odd, hopefully you know how to fix this, thank you.

Comment: Try copying the above code into a new project. I just did that and it worked.

Comment: Can you guys suggest other options while I try this code??